# How to make an url page compatible for iPhone UIWebView in objective c

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have built an application for iPhone.

In this app I need to use an url in the `UIWebView`.

I have implemented like this

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq";

// Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

// URL Request Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

// Load the request in the UIWebView.
[documentsWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

The problem is that the web site is shown using zoom factor 100%. Hence my users have to scroll both vertically and horizontally. How do I adjust the zoom factor so that only vertical scrolling is required per default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to turn on:

```
documentsWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

No we cannot. It's web-server side check.

From the web-server side it required to check which client browser is being used (using user-agent).

Accordingly server will navigated to specific page or load css.

There is nothing required from device-end.

Answer (score 0):

On UIWebView there are many settings: enable/diable zoom, javascript, there are to many, better check documentation for that.

Your problem solution will be a server side html coding. There you need to check the client, his resolution and such.

Pls check in google "responsive layout" for html page.